# Differences b/n mapState, mapGetters, mapActions, mapMutations in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have been using vue/vuex for months and I see `mapState`, `mapGetters`, `mapActions`, `mapMutations` but don't know what they do except for `mapState`.

This is how I use `mapState`

```
// mutations.js 
user: {
   address: {},
   name: '',
   age: ''
}
```

and in my code I have something like this:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data: {},

  computed: {
   ...mapState({
    address: state => state.user.address
   })
  }
}
```

then I can use address anywhere, but I don't know what the others are used for.

can someone give a simple example? thanks

Comment: Well, it is not very clear to me, that is why i took the test to write down the question example so I wanted to know. I have read that documentation and came here to ask.

Comment: Emile, there is no need to be rude.  Almost all of the answers on SO can be found in documentation somewhere.  That does not mean the question should not be asked.

Answer (score 41):

None of those mappers are mandatory. Their goal is just to make easy to create computed properties or methods in the components. They are DRY (avoid duplication) at its best.

`mapState` is a helper that simplifies creating a **computed** property that reflects the value of a given state.

Similarly:

- `mapGetters` is a helper that simplifies creating a **computed** property that reflects the value returned by a given getter.

  - Note that even [**method-style** getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html#method-style-access) should be mapped to computed properties.
- `mapActions` is a helper that simplifies creating a **method** that would be equivalent as calling `dispatch` on an action.
- `mapMutations` is a helper that simplifies creating a **method** that would be equivalent as calling `commit` on an mutation.

Since code helps, the demo below shows **examples of using all those mappers**, and their **equivalent without mappers**. Their behavior is exactly the same. The mappers just allow you to write with less code (consider that this will be repeated in many, many components of your app).

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {name: "John"},
  mutations: {
   changeName(state, data) {
     state.name = data
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchRandomName({ commit }) {
      let randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1  ;
      axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users/" + randomId).then(response => {
        commit('changeName', response.data.data.first_name)
      })
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getName: state => state.name,
    getTransformedName: (state) => (upperOrLower) => {
      return upperOrLower ? state.name.toUpperCase() : state.name.toLowerCase()
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  data: { newName: 'Bob' },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState(['name']),
    nameNoMapper() { return this.$store.state.name },
    ...Vuex.mapGetters(['getName', 'getTransformedName']),
    getNameNoMapper() { return this.$store.getters.getName },
    getTransformedNameNoMapper() { return this.$store.getters.getTransformedName }
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapActions(['fetchRandomName']),
    ...Vuex.mapMutations(['changeName']),
    fetchRandomNameNoMapper() { this.$store.dispatch('fetchRandomName') },
    changeNameNoMapper(newName) { this.$store.commit('changeName', newName) },
  }
})
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 250px">With Mappers</td>
      <td style="width: 310px">Without Mappers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        name: {{ name }}<br>
        getName: {{ getName }}<br>
        getTransformedName(true): {{ getTransformedName(true) }}<br>
        getTransformedName(false): {{ getTransformedName(false) }}
      </td>
      <td>
        nameNoMapper: {{ nameNoMapper }}<br>
        getNameNoMapper: {{ getNameNoMapper }}<br>
        getTransformedNameNoMapper(true): {{ getTransformedNameNoMapper(true) }}<br>
        getTransformedNameNoMapper(false): {{ getTransformedNameNoMapper(false) }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <button @click="fetchRandomName">ACTION: fetchRandomName</button> - <button @click="fetchRandomNameNoMapper">ACTION: fetchRandomNameNoMapper</button><br>
  <hr>
  <input v-model="newName"><button @click="changeName(newName)">MUTATION: changeName</button><button @click="changeNameNoMapper(newName)">MUTATION: changeNameNoMapper</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any difference in terms of performance when using `mapGetters` and `mapState` if I just want to return the same value?

Comment: @IrfandyJip no, it's the same, don't work. If your getter does no calculations, the difference is in the order of nanoseconds (the temperature of the computer should have a higher impact )

Comment: Great explanation. However when I try to call a mutation from a component directly, it always tells me `undefined local mutation`. I can't even dispatch an action on the store, I have to map the action and call it. Any particular reason?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Perhaps you are not adding the namespace prefix to the name of the mutation you are calling directly.